# add Qrcode to powerbuilder 10.5 datawindow

Tags: sybase, qr-code, powerbuilder, datawindow

We use powerbuilder10.5  - dataWindow  to view  Reports  from  Sybase Database ,
is There any way to generate QR Code to the and add it to the Report

Answer (score 1):

You will have to either write your own COM .dll or find one online to use in PowerBuilder.  There are many, many of these available via an online search (one such component is QRCoder, written in .Net-C#).  In a nutshell these take a string and then output a bitmap / image.  You will then have to place the bitmap into the report in an image column.